# Show message on page after editing from jeditable plugin

Tags: jquery

i am working in MVC and using jquery.jeditable plugin.The editing is working fine in grid.when i update the content in grid & click on enter the edit post from my controller cllass is called & returns a string as updated text.

i want to show a message somewhere else on my page after the update is done.

```
[HttpPost]public string edit(FormCollection collection)

{.....

// show success message on page other then grid column

... return <updated column value>;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about showing a message after ajax call, then just show it ;) What is the problem?

```
// variant 1:
alert(response);
// variant 2:
$.growlUI("Server response", response); // using blockUI plugin

// or any other popup div with the information from ajax http request
```

If you return more than one value, then return them as a JSON-object, like this:

```
return "{ updatedColumnValue: " + value + ", msgtext: '" + msgtext.Replace("'", @"\'") + "' }";
```

If you want to show something after postback, then make some UserControl visible where your message will be diplayed.